# Creating new components in visual c#

Tags: c#, components

Can u tell me how can i create my own visual components in c#.
which source do u advise?

Answer (score 5):

There are several different ways to create new controls in C#:

1. The first way involves extending an *existing* control class, done either by deriving from the [`System.Windows.Forms.Control` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) (which is the base class for all controls in WinForms), or from one of its more specific subclasses (`TextBox`, `Button`, etc.).

   The `Control` class actually derives from [`System.ComponentModel.Component`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx), but it adds the necessary magic that gives the component a visual interface, as you requested—a control is a component that is displayed on the screen and that presents an interface the user can interact with.
2. The second way involves creating a custom user control. The Add New Item wizard in Visual Studio has a single-click option for inserting a new user control into your project, or you can manually derive from the [`System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.usercontrol.aspx).

   The advantage of a user control is that it is a *container* control, meaning that you can put several different controls inside of a single control. This is handy for building more complex controls, rather than simply extending (or adding functionality to) one of the built-in controls.

Controls created using either of these methods can be used on a different form within your application.

Comment: Just create a project class library with a class descendant from UserControl, will turn my control able to be inserted in toolbox controls?

Answer (score 0):

Try Windows Forms Controls Libarary, or if you are WPF , you can use WPF Controls Library. You may also go through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207(v=vs.71).aspx